# World Cup: Is it worth to bet each match twice?

Tags: probability

Let's assume we get **1 point for predicting the result** (win/lose/draw) and **3 points for predicting correct score for both teams** (e.g. 3:2).

We've got two separate accounts where we can bet, my question is:

(1) **does betting twice each match** (once per account, each bet with different score) allows you to get more points on one of the accounts than on account when you bet only once?

(2) Is it possible to calculate **how probable** it is to get better result with two accounts?

**Edit and clarification:** Betting doesn't cost money, it's just a company game. **My friend argued that if he could bet from two accounts he would be much more successful and I think it wouldn't increase his chances to win much since this is not entirely random but I'm lacking any skills to prove the gain would be insignificant.**

What I mean in question 1 is that **if you bet on one account you choose the most probable outcome (according to your knowledge) so the second account would always get only less probable outcomes** which shouldn't increase chances since match results aren't totaly random (I was able to correctly guess outcome of almost half of matches and the account with my second guesses would do worse). So I've got two betting models: primary and secondary and I'd like to calculate how likely it is that using two models can give me better overall result on one of the accounts than using just primary model. I think it may be impossible but I'm a noob so maybe you guys can help me.

Comment: Of course it's better. If there's no penalty to getting something wrong, you have an additional opportunity to score some points. Is there some constraint you forgot to include in the question?

Comment: @CloseToC You lose money when you lose a bet: that's the constraint.

Comment: @whuber: I don't think the question makes this clear. The accounts could be part of a competition (say, within a company) that doesn't cost money. If each bet does cost money, then the question of "is it worth it" depends on how much a bet costs points are "valued" (perhaps it costs $100 per bet and the points are only good for bragging rights- who knows?). I think this question needs more information.

Comment: I'd agree with @DavidRobinson. The first question is uninteresting (or poorly phrased) - it's almost assured that if you make different bets that one account will have more points than the other. As for the second question, it depends on the prediction strategy, if you lose points when you guess incorrectly, and the individual probabilities of each score happening, which is incredibly hard to calculate.